# How to add jQuery listener to CakePHP time input?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, input, time

I've been using CakePHP 2.x to develop a web application that has a simple form that sends an email request to a mailbox.

For part of the form it asks the user to supply a date and time. The date part uses the jQuery UI datepicker and the time part is using CakePHP's form helper type of time.

I want to be able to perform checks on the content entered when the user changes the values of the input fields using javascript/jQuery. It's working fine for the date but I cannot seem to add the listener to the Time['hour'] and Time['min'] fields.

Here is the code from the view:

```
echo $this->Form->create('Av', array('inputDefaults' => array('div' => true)));
echo $this->Form->input('Date', array('label' => 'Event date *'));
echo $this->Form->input('Time', array('type' => 'time', 'label' => 'Event time *', 'timeFormat' => 24, 'interval' => 5));
echo $this->Form->end('Submit');
```

And here is the javascript I have been working on:

```
$(function() {
    $('#AvDate').datepicker({
        dateFormat: "dd MM yy",
        minDate: new Date(),
        maxDate: "+1y",
        autoSize: true,
        firstDate: 1
    });

    $('#AvDate').change(function() {
        checkDateDifference();
    });

    $('#AvTimeHour').change(function() {
        checkDateDifference();
    });

    $('#AvTimeMinute').change(function() {
        checkDateDifference();
    });
});

function checkDateDifference() {
    var date = $('#AvDate').val();
    var hour = $('#AvTimeMinute').val();

    console.log(hour);
}
```

Does anyone have any tips/suggestions that could help me achieve the desired functionality?

Comment: I guess your selectors are wrong give the input a name type or id and then you can select it with jquery

Answer (score 0):

After @Roland suggested my selectors were wrong I rewrote all the field inputs and gave them id values of 'AvDate' and 'AvTime' which is what CakePHP would have defaulted them to anyway and this caused the minute input for 'AvTime' to change from 'AvTimeMin' to 'AvTimeMinute'. After adjusting the javascript/jQuery to take into account the change it started to work.

Here is the updated code for anyone interested:

```
echo $this->Form->create('Av', array('inputDefaults' => array('div' => true)));
echo $this->Form->input('Date', array('label' => 'Event date *', 'id' => 'AvDate'));
echo $this->Form->input('Time', array('type' => 'time', 'label' => 'Event time *', 'timeFormat' => 24, 'interval' => 5, 'id' => 'AvTime'));
echo $this->Form->end('Submit');
```

And the javascript:

```
$(function() {
    $('#AvDate').datepicker({
        dateFormat: "dd MM yy",
        minDate: new Date(),
        maxDate: "+1y",
        autoSize: true,
        firstDate: 1
    });

    $('#AvDate').change(function() {
        checkDateDifference();
    });

    $('#AvTimeHour').change(function() {
        checkDateDifference();
    });

    $('#AvTimeMinute').change(function() {
        checkDateDifference();
    });
});

function checkDateDifference() {
    var date = $('#AvDate').val();
    var hour = $('#AvTimeHour').val();
    var minute = $('#AvTimeMinute').val();

    console.log(date + ' ' + hour + ':' + minute);
}
```